# Conditioned URL masking

Tags: string, url, variables, conditional-statements, masking

Say I have two domains from two different servers. **A.com** which people visit, and **B.com** which hosts the files they view.
When a person views *A.com/file* they are actually viewing *B.com/file*.
Of course for just a few pages I could do URL masking (like iframe), but that becomes quickly impractical when new pages are constantly being made.

So how would I go about creating a condition to automatically mask new links genreated on B.com for A.com?

(If *B.com/new* exists, entering *A.com/new* masks that).

Additionally, is it possible, through A.com, for all B.com links to open as A.com links?

Thank you very, very much.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, what have you tried so far? Take a look at the `header`-method of php and generally `htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it.
You could just alias A.com to be B.com which is what DNS sometimes does.

Also, B.com links could open as A.com when you provide a redirection protocol that would direct the page to the A.com link and the user would then see the URL as A.com.

*This is exactly what happens when you enter fb.com, you are redirected to facebook.com*